# How to replace text in element from textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have some element with some data. I need to create changing field for it. So i use textarea to change text in this element. Everything working nice but when i want to add condtion with text langht something is not working right... This is my code and some fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qzzKA/) for it. Thx for help...

```
<div class="textchange_box">
    <span class="desc">data<br>data
    </span>
    <textarea name="desc" class="textfield"></textarea>
    <span class="change">change</span>
    <span class="save">save</span>
</div>​
```

and jquery:

```
$(".change").live('click', function () {
    $(this).prev('.textfield').css('display','block');
    $(this).prevAll('.desc').css('display','none');
    $(this).next('.save').css('display','block');
    $(this).css('display','none');
});
$(".save").live('click', function () {
    var default_value = $(this).prev('.desc').text().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br/>");
    var actual_value = $(this).prev('.textfield').text().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />");
    $(this).prevAll('.textfield').css('display','none');
    $(this).prev('.change').css('display','block');
    $(this).css('display','none');
    if (actual_value.length < 0) {
        $(this).prev('.desc').replaceWith('<span class="desc">' + default_value +'</span>');
    }
    else if (actual_value.length > 0) {
        $(this).prev('.desc').replaceWith('<span class="desc">' + actual_value +'</span>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried use `.val()` instead `.text()`?

Comment: Not related to your question, but note that using spans as links is an accessibility failure because they won't work for users who don't or can't use a mouse or other pointing device.

Comment: thx i will change it but now i nee to fix this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your following line:

```
if (actual_value.length < 0) {
```

for this one:

```
if (actual_value.length <= 0) {
```

because when a string is empty its length is zero not a negative number.

**UPDATE:**
You have other errors, your following two lines:

```
var default_value = $(this).prev('.desc').text().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br/>");
var actual_value = $(this).prev('.textfield').text().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />");
```

should be like this:

```
var default_value = $(this).prevAll('.desc').text().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br/>");
var actual_value = $(this).prevAll('.textfield').val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />");
```

So using `prevAll()` instead of `prev()` and using `val()` for textarea instead of `text()` .

Also you need to use `prevAll()` here:

```
$(this).prev('.desc').replaceWith('<span class="desc">' + actual_value +'</span>');
```

so it would be:

```
$(this).prevAll('.desc').replaceWith('<span class="desc">' + actual_value +'</span>');
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qzzKA/2/) .

Basically the most common error is you thought `.prev()` will traverse all previous siblings, while for that you have to use `prevAll()`

Comment: Or even `=== 0`, since it can't be negative.

Comment: This does not change anything

Comment: I deeper looked at your fiddle and catch some more errors, I've updated my answer with them and also posted a working fiddle, check it out :-)

Comment: lovely, thx man it work perfect, but i have problem with break lines, they return to one line when i'm editing them...